# How to exclude some word in string in regex (to replace using javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to select word between two (") and exclude other word outside (") to replace string using javascript replace. This is my string

> The receptionist: "Okay, please wait a moment." After a while, the
> receptionist smiled and said, "Congratulations, you have obtained a
> certificate of exemption from the exam for job transfer. With it, you
> can use it after you reach a certain Level. After completing the job
> transfer task, you can directly transfer to a specific occupation, a
> very convenient little gift."

I want to select `"Okay, please wait a moment."` and `"Congratulations, you have obtained a certificate of exemption from the exam for job transfer. With it, you can use it after you reach a certain Level. After completing the job transfer task, you can directly transfer to a specific occupation, a very convenient little gift."` and exclude other.

I try `/".+"/g` and it include all from `"okay` to `gift."` and not exclude other
Please help me and thank you

Comment: use this `"(.*?)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Think its could works: `/("[^"]+")/g`

This regexp match any group of words that have an initial `"`, one or more characters different to `"` and finally ends with a `"`
You can see it in this [regex101](https://regex101.com/) image
[image: result of the regex]

Comment: '/"(.*?)"/g' '/("[^"]+")/g' and '/".+?"/g' work well with my string 
Is this three same